# How to draw SVG images stored in PostGIS with Mapserver?

Tags: mapserver

I have a table in PostGIS with two columns. In first are stored SVG images as text. In second is geometry (Point in epsg 4326). 
Is it possible to draw SVGs from PostGIS on position given in the geometry column with Mapserver?